# Specify initial geometry for any window with Gnome 3

Tags: gnome, nautilus

I would like to open one or more Nautilus windows from the command line or a script at certain positions on my screen/desktop while in Gnome 3. I could do this in Ubuntu 11.10 by specifying the geometry. For example, to open the window at the bottom right corner from the command line I could use:

```
nautilus --geometry 600x475-0-0 ~/mystuff
```

However, in Ubuntu 12.04 using Gnome 3 the geometry option is ignored or overridden. 
Is there a way to arbitrarily position the Nautilus (or any application) windows when starting them from command line or scripts?

Comment: _confused_  ..Do you want a fixed position for different apps? or different Positions for same app?...

Comment: Use the _Place Window_ tool in **CCSM**... will help a bit...

Answer (score 4):

I am having the same issue under 12.04 with Gnome Classic & compiz.

The only (command line) workaround I have found so far is to follow up the nautilus call with an invocation of wmctrl similar to this:

```
wmctrl -Fr "your exact window title" -e '0,0,0,400,1080'
```

wmctrl has a few different ways of selecting windows, and is just an apt-get away.